# one to many relationship in laravel fail to save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

i have a one to many relationships between notification table and alerFrequency table.all the models are working fine, the only thing it miss is the following.
the time stamp in the alertFrequency table for specific websites recorded in the notification table, is used to calculate the elapse time and then determine either to send notification or not, and either to insert a new record to the alertfrequency table. i have a controller class called a guzzle controller. the function called add is suposed to do that but failed, but i have a function called addToNotification, it attaches vales in to the pivot table and is doing fine. i would appreciate nay suggestions and helps ?

```
private function addStatusToNotification(Notification $notification, Status $status, $resCode)    {
    $notification->statuses()->attach($status, [
        'values' => strval($resCode)
    ]);
}

/*function to add new time stamp into the alertFrequency table*/
private function add(Notification $notification, AlertFrequency $alertTime){
    $notification->alertFrequencies()->save($alertTime);
}

private function sendNotification(Notification $notification, $status_health, $alert_frequency, $resCode,$alertTime, AlertFrequency $alert)    {       
    // If this is the first time we check, OR if the status changed from up to down and vice versa, notify!!!
    if (empty($status_health['timestamp']) || Notification::health($resCode) <> Notification::health($status_health['value'])){
        $this->report($notification,$resCode);
        return;
    }
    // If the website is (still) down and the alert frequency is exceeded, notify!!!
    if(Notification::health($resCode) === 'down' && \Carbon\Carbon::parse($alertTime)->diffInMinutes() >= $alert_frequency){            
        $this->report($notification,$resCode);
       //expected to save the new record in the alertFrequencies table but failed to do so
        $this->add($notification,$alert);
    }
}

public function status()
{
    $notifications = Notification::where('active', 1)->get();

    $alert = AlertFrequency::with('notification')->first();

    $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();

    foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
        $this->updateStatus($notification, $status,$alert);
    }  
}

private function updateStatus(Notification $notification, Status $status, AlertFrequency $alert)
{
    $status_health = $notification->status('health');
    $check = empty($status_health['timestamp']);
    $elapsed_time = $check ? 10000 : \Carbon\Carbon::parse($status_health['timestamp'])->diffInMinutes();

    $check_frequency = $this->getCheckFrequency($notification);       
    /* create an attachemtn in to the alerFrequenct table*/        
    $alertTime = $notification->getLastTimestampAttribute();     

    if ($check || $elapsed_time >= $check_frequency) {
        $resCode = $this->getStatusCode($notification->website_url);
        $this->addStatusToNotification($notification, $status, $resCode);
        $this->sendNotification(
            $notification,
            $status_health,
            $this->getAlertFrequency($notification),
            $resCode,
            $alertTime,
            $alert
        );            
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont understand the question

Comment: @ Paras : the notification table has the website urls saved and the alerfrequencies table stores the notification_id and the created_at time stamp. every time a add a new website url into the notification table, it also adds the notification_id(foreign key),so far is fine. in my guzzle controller i have a function called add which will save into the alerFrequencies table the notification_id and created_at time stamp. this add function should add to the database if the sendNotification function called it ?

Comment: i hope it will help u understand it better